# Set origin Percentage SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I am working with C++ SFML and I am making a game were you have a 2D world and trees and stone and other. I need the base of each object to be in the center of the coordinate of it but for example stone has a texture of 64 x 64 and the tree has 128 by 128. Is there any way to use sprite.setOrigin(x, y) were x and y are a percentage of the photo I am printing?

Comment: Take the width and height, divide by two?

Comment: I am printing over 150 images at a time. If I take the width and height of all pictures and divide them 150 * 2 = 300 each tick I think  lag will apear

Comment: No, it won't. A typical CPU can do millions (if not billions) of floating point divisions per second.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough details as to how you're implementing all of this but, I'm assuming tress and stones and whatnot are all objects of the same class, if so, you can have a constructor that takes a bunch of parameters, including the texture, and calculates the origin based on it's size, just have all the different objects (trees, stones, etc...) stored somewhere, and every time you want spawn something you just copy one of the already initialized objects.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the sprite you can do:

```cpp
sf::Sprite sprt;
// load stuff
sf::Vector2f size = sprt.getTexture().getSize();
```

And in your case, you can use this to set the origine of your sprite to the center:

```cpp
sprt.setOrigin(size.x / 2, size.y / 2);
```